# Flutter: Scrolling with Nested Widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have one page in my flutter app that is basically a big list with multiple nested lists.  No matter what type of widgets I use, the screen won't scroll properly.  It does the scroll where it bounces to the top and doesn't let the user scroll all the way down.  How can I get this to be scrollable?

Here is the code from the main page:

```
body: CustomScrollView(
    physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child:
                Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
              new AlertItems(ptid: ptid),
            ])),
        Container(
            child:
                Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
          new OpenAppts(ptid: ptid),
        ])),
        Container(
            child:
                Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
          new OpenLabs(ptid: ptid),
        ])),
      ])),
    ],
  ),
```

And then the included AlertItems (as an example) looks like this:

```
return ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.total,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  newDate = DateTime.parse(
                      snapshot.data.entry[index].resource.date);
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(
                            Icons.announcement,
                            color: Colors.orange[400],
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                              snapshot.data.total.toString() +
                                  ' Open Items ',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        ),
                        Divider(height: 5.0),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                              formatDate(newDate, [m, '/', d, '/', yyyy])),
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.entry[index].resource
                                  .messageSubject ??
                              'No Subject'),
                          leading: Image(
                            image: AssetImage('images/messaging.png'),
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
```

Comment: try `physics: ScrollPhysics()` for both the `ListView` and the `CustomScrollView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `physics: ScrollPhysics()` for both the `ListView` and the `CustomScrollView`should work.

Answer (score 0):

use `NestedScrollView` rather than `CustomScrollView`  you can get full expanation and example code here [NestedScrollView Flutter Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html)